# Runtime Error with the NS.GetSharedDefaultFolder Method

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

Running it from MS Access (2007) via the Outlook Interop library.  I get the error -2147221219 (8004011d) from the starred line on one user account, but not on another.  Error appears to be related to permissions, and both accounts have Full Access permissions to the account who's calendar I'm trying to open and can open and create appointments to it via Outlook.  Sample code

```
Public Function NewApt(MtgDate As Date, Cat As String)

Dim objOLApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objCalendar As Outlook.Folder
Dim NewMtg As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim Org As Outlook.Recipient

Set objOLApp = New Outlook.Application
Set objNS = objOLApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Org = objNS.CreateRecipient("tuser@somewhere.com")
Org.Resolve
If Org.Resolved Then
    ** Set objCalendar = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Org, olFolderCalendar)
Else
    MsgBox "Scheduling User failed to resolve, see Crimius."
    Exit Function
End If
...
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried `objNS.Logon` ?

Comment: It was my understanding that the Logon method would hijack an existing session and change their working profile, so we decided to try avoiding that (since several of our users like to have 40 outlook messages open then complain that their system is slow).  Is this not the case?

Comment: No, Logon will log to the profile if Outlook has just been started. It will do nothing if it is already running. Secondly, try to add both mailboxes as delegate stores (Advanced tab of the Exchange account properties dialog). Can you browse both mailboxes?

Answer (score 1):

I know one reason why this error may appear.
Whe you use the `GetSharedDefaultFolder` method and the recipient in parameter 1 (Recipient) is hidden from the global address list such an error can occur:

```
COMException (0x8004011D):
The operation failed because of a registry or installation problem. Restart Outlook and try again. If the problem persists, reinstall.
```

Comment: This can also happen if Outlook is in cached mode and the Outlook Offline Global Address Book is not up to date - either not generated on the server (it's typically generated only daily) or not downloaded by the client.

Comment: How do you fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, the Outlook-Datafile is protected by password.
Switch to Outlook, enter the Password for the Outlook-Container, and then try again.

Answer (score -2):

I had exactly the same issue. A VBA module that ran during years suddenly refused to. After verification it turned out that the internal e-mail addresses changed to previous runs of the macro...

Changing to email addresses solved the problem.